# Unable to parallelize a list in Scala

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, spark-streaming, avro

I am unable to parallelize a list in scala, getting java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    messages.foreachRDD( rdd => {
       for(avroLine <- rdd){
        val record = Injection.injection.invert(avroLine.getBytes).get
        val field1Value = record.get("username")
        val jsonStrings=Seq(record.toString())
        val newRow = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(record.toString()))
            }
            })
```

**output**

```
 jsonStrings...List({"username": "user_118", "tweet": "tweet_218", "timestamp": 18})
```

**Exception**

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.capitalone.AvroConsumer$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AvroConsumer.scala:83)
at com.capitalone.AvroConsumer$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AvroConsumer.scala:74)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.foreach(CompletionIterator.scala:26)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create an RDD in the spark worker context.  While `foreachRDD` operates in the driver, the `foreach` operation you perform on each RDD is distributed to the workers.  It seems unlikely that you actually want to create a new RDD for each line of the input stream.

Update after comments:

It's hard to have this discussion in a comment thread where there is no formatting for code.  My basic question is why aren't you doing something like this:

```
val messages: ReceiverInputDStream[String] = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, rabbitParams)
def toJsonString(message: String): String = SparkUtils.getRecordInjection(QUEUE_NAME).invert(message.getBytes()).get
val jsonStrings: DStream[String] = messages map toJsonString
```

I haven't bothered to figure out and track down all the libraries you're using (please, next time, submit a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so I haven't tried to compile that.  But it looks like all you want is to map each input message to a JSON string.  Maybe you want to do something fancy with the resulting DStream of Strings but that might be a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to convert my RabbitMQ AVRO binary streams using avro invert and then saving as a .csv file to filesystem.
val messages = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, rabbitParams);
   messages.foreachRDD( rdd => {
 for(avroLine <- messages){
      val record = SparkUtils.getRecordInjection(QUEUE_NAME).invert(rdd.getBytes).get;
       val jsonStrings: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq(record.toString()));
       val result = sqlContext.read.json(jsonStrings).toDF();
result.write.mode("Append").csv("/Users/Documents/rabbitmq/consumer-out/");
       }})

Comment: It very much looks like you are trying to generate one record of output for each record of input.  Is that correct?  Is there a reason that you cannot just use `map` for this translation?

Comment: Yes, my consumer runs every 15min and consumes all the streams. Also I tried map function in this way, val messages = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, rabbitParams);messages.foreachRDD( rdd => {val record = rdd.map (message => SparkUtils.getRecordInjection(QUEUE_NAME).invert(message.getBytes).get);val jsonStrings: RDD[String] = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(record.toString())); But, at least with my prev process, I could convert my binary streams to readable, but  I'm getting the below output with map. jsonStrings...ParallelCollectionRDD[42] at parallelize at AVROMqStreaming.scala:62

Comment: Updated answer based on the above comment, which is still trying to create an RDD in the map function.  Hoping my response clear.

Comment: Thanks for the your reply, I will try it out and I posted my full code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
def toJsonString(message: String): String = {val record = 

SparkUtils.getRecordInjection(QUEUE_NAME).invert(message.getBytes()).get  }
dStreams.foreachRDD( rdd => {
val jsonStrings = rdd.map (stream =>toJsonString(stream))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonStrings)
df.write.mode("Append").csv("/Users/Documents/kafka-poc/consumer-out/def/")}
```

Comment: Please point out the part of the code that solved your problem.